# Getting errors while sending emails via Powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I'm trying to send an email with a Powershell script, when I run my program as is I get an error that looks like this:

```
Exception setting "Add": "Cannot set the Value property for PSMemberInfo object of type 
"System.Management.Automation.PSMethod"."
At C:\Users\documents\eventSender.ps1:11 char:1
+ $emailMessageObject.To.Add = $toEmailAddress
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting

'Attachments' is a ReadOnly property.
At C:\Users\documents\eventSender.ps1:14 char:1
+ $emailMessageObject.Attachments = $currentAttachment
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "A recipient must be specified."
At C:\Users\documents\eventSender.ps1:18 char:1
+ $smtpClient.Send($emailMessageObject)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

Now I'm fairly new to powershell so I don't really understand the error, how I'm trying to send the message looks like this:

```
$todaysDate = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date
$smtpServerAddress = "smtp.google.com"
$toEmailAddress = "admins@me.com"
$fromEmailAddress = "me@me.com"
$subjectMessage = "Files for date -> $todaysDate"
$body = "log files sent on $todaysDate (this is a test)"
$currentAttachment = "C:/Users/Downloads/TBG-1.htm"

$emailMessageObject = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMessageObject.From = $fromEmailAddress
$emailMessageObject.To.Add = $toEmailAddress
$emailMessageObject.Subject = $subjectMessage
$emailMessageObject.Body = $body
$emailMessageObject.Attachments = $currentAttachment

$smtpClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServerAddress, 587)
$smtpClient.EnableSsl = $true
$smtpClient.Send($emailMessageObject)
```

What am I doing wrong to where I am getting this error message, also do I need to have credentials that match my email address to send this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Send-MailMessage` in place of `System.Net.Mail.Message`.

I find the easiest way is through Splatting:

```
$Splat = @{ 
    To         =$toEmailAddress  
    Body       =$body
    Subject    =$subjectMessage  
    SmtpServer =$smtpServerAddress  
    From       =$fromEmailAddress
    Attachements = $currentAttachment    
    } 

    Send-MailMessage @Splat
```

You should only have to specify credentials if your exchange requires that the sender be authorized. If so, you would simply just change the `$Splat` to:

```
 $Splat = @{ 
    To         =$toEmailAddress  
    Body       =$body
    Subject    =$subjectMessage  
    SmtpServer =$smtpServerAddress  
    From       =$fromEmailAddress
    Attachements = $currentAttachment 
    Crendential = $creds   
    } 

    Send-MailMessage @Splat
```

Answer (score 0):

`MailMessage.To.Add()` is a method, so you have to call it like this `$emailMessageObject.To.Add($toEmailAddress)`

`MailMessage.Attachments` is also a collection, so you have to add the item with `$emailMessageObject.Attachments.Add($currentAttachment)`

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx)